# Initiate script in embedded browser from the container application

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

If I have an embedded browser in a windows form, is it possible to initiate a javascript method from the container application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Document.InvokeScript, as outlined in this excellent MSDN article:

[How to: Implement Two-Way Communication Between DHTML Code and Client Application Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes There is..

```
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("doSomething()");
```